# Wildfly 14 Web Console adding spaces in the module options

Tags: wildfly, web-console, wildfly-16, wildfly-14

I am trying to add a security domain in the web console of wildfly. So `Configuration > Subsystems > System > Security > domain name`. In the authentication, Authentication Module, Module Option you can add the options, but I can't add a module I need because it has a space in the option.

But I get the error "Invalid format: Add new properties as key =value pairs, the special character allowed in the value are - :@;=?!#$%&[]" due to the space.

I would be something like Module Options "test=testfirstpart secondpart"

I know it's likely the cli works for this operation, but I'm asking without using that.